what type of activity level should i choose?
I'm not entirely sure what I am; either sedentary or lightly active. I usually average my steps from 7k-10k a day but besides that I don't really exercise much, perhaps a 1-minute plank 3 times a day a few days out of the week but other than that I never work out. I'm thinking sedentary but I'm not sure. It's not like I sit all day but I don't lift crazy heavy things either.

Choose for what? Are you completing a survey?

Usually the calorie counter app that you are attempting to use will have an explanation of the different selections. When in doubt, pick the lower activity setting.
